# Updating table in execution time vue js 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

i´m trying to send data to my table in execution time when i clicked my button from my form.

I´m using composition API and composables. I´m getting my data from my axios post from my composable into my parent component. I need send it to my child component table. For this, i´m using ref and props:

parentComponent:

```
setup(props, context) {

  const { getRegisters, deleteCalls, queryForKeywords, getResults, getItems } = useNregister()
  var param_search = {};
  const register_data = ref([])

register_data.value = await getRegisters( toRef(param_search,'param_search') );
```

and retuning `register_data`

```
return { 
   register_data
}
```

when include my child component i´m sending this ref:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade-in active" id="nasigned">
    <div id="app5">
       <nAsignedCalls :register_data="register_data"></nAsignedCalls> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my component i have a v-for that i know my data it´s arriving because console.log() returned me one index that was indefined but my result it´s my empty table.

in my child compontent i have:

```
<template v-for="item in register_data"> 
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ (item.name) ? item.name : '' }} </td>
                    <td>{{ (item.address) ? item.address : ''}}</td>
                    <td>{{ (item.province) ? item.province : ''}} </td>

export default defineComponent({
        name: 'nAsignedCalls',    
        data(){
            return{
                items: [],
                    pagination: {
                         current_page: 1,
                   },
                }
            },
            props: { 
              register_data: {
                type: Array,
                default: () => ([])
              } 
            },
```

and result it´s console.log() it´s from my form component, when i clicked my button call function and call to my composable, this it´s result query composable:

[image]

i have all my code and my components in:

[here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

thanks for readme, and sorry for my bad english

Comment: So what is actual question?

Comment: @lysy.vlc how i can to do for show my data in my table

Comment: Would you be able to create a *runnable* [mcve]? What you pasted is incomplete and cannot be run, so we can't tell why it's not working. Consider using codesandbox to create a runnable snippet and using [prettier](https://prettier.io/playground/) to format the code in the question.

Comment: The problem with Vue playground is you can't install any packages, whereas in codesandbox you can simply import your local project, it builds it on the fly and it just runs. In what you posted, we have no way of knowing what's in `'../../composables/ncalls'`

Comment: @tao thanks for your response. Only i want share with you all my file structure and logic. Because althought run my example, need inter API to show all data... Only wanted this. I´m sorry if my shared it´s incorrectly. But with this code and my img in question, i believe that you can show my error.

Comment: You can mock the api with a json file containing some dummy data. And the api call is just a function `import data from './data.json'; export const myApiCall = () => Promise.resolve({ data })`. Without some dummy data we can't see how it all works.